# SSMS (2014) cannot connect to remote DB on local network

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, team-foundation-server, windows-8.1, visual-studio, sql-server-2014

To start, this set up *used* to work. I wanted to help on a friend's project and installed git and vagrant and somewhere between the last time I opened my own project (using the setup listed below) and today, it has stopped working.

Current set up:

- VS2013 on local dev on windows 8.1 (I know, don't judge me, please)
- TFS Express on remote Server 2012 R2, connecting via both http and TFS in VS,
- SQL Server 2014 on remote and local with db hosted on said server 2012 remote
- SSMS to manage SQL server

Here are the symptoms:

- Server 2012:

  - When remoting into Server2012 (called "TheBeast"), remote desktop works fine, TFS admin works fine, TFS via localhost http works fine, SQL server works fine. It has no dev tools and has had absolutely no configuration changes. In short, the server is 100% working.
  - TheBeast is not using DHCP but is assigned a *.150 IP on a class C network range. All devices on the network are in the same subnet.
- local dev (again, worked previously)

  - local SSMS can connect to local SQL Server.
  - local SSMS cannot connect to remote SQL on TheBeast. When attempting to use Windows Credentials, it fails with an invalid password error (as it should). Attempting to connect with sa creds, it never resolves (that is to say it just endlessly sits there with no connection but no error).
  - Cannot hit TFS on TheBeast using http on the port I set up (8080).
  - VS2013 TFS cannot connect to the server.
  - I can remote into TheBeast via Remote Desktop just fine all day long.

To be sure, I have completely turned OFF windows firewall and made sure that I have no other security software running.

I have tried the steps [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/407629/sql-server-2012-i-can-connect-locally-but-not-remotelly) and have verified that the settings were correct (they are).

In case it is important, my network setup is as follows:

- Wireless router connected to cable modem.
- Ethernet line to another router just for TheBeast
- TheBeast using wired ethernet to the second router.

No configuration changes have been made to either router. I have power cycled every router as well as the modem. I have uninstalled Vagrant and Git to be sure. My guess is that one of those two have done something to the port or permissions (or similar) and didn't clean up after themselves after uninstall.

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the router the server was connected to is in the process of dying. For whatever reason, only a limited set of protocols and services are available through it. Plugged the box containing the services into another router and the problems instantly went away.